# Pushdown automaton for  = { ∈ {, }∗∣#() ≠ 2 ⋅ #()}

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

I have been trying to build pushdown automaton but no clue or idea on how to start.

I got the solution but I cannot get it,

[Solution I received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsWgR.png)

What I was thinking is $2$ possible variations
#() < 2 ⋅ #()
Or
#() > 2 ⋅ #()

If someone can just explain me this solution ill be more that happy (:

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)